# How to return the column with the value closest to an inputed value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, math

I have a dataframe `stock_data_5y.txt` and I'm writing a function with input arguments `initial_price` and `volatility`.

In dataframe `stock_data_5y.txt`, the first row indicates the value used for volatility when the data was generated, the second row indicates the initial prices for each stock and so on.

```py
5.4 3.0 3.4 1.2 1.0 4.6 2.6 0.4 1.4 0.8 4.2 4.0 5.2 1.6 4.8 3.8 2.8 2.4 0.2 0.6
150.0 370.0 100.0 210.0 590.0 400.0 510.0 140.0 550.0 440.0 330.0 200.0 380.0 260.0 160.0 360.0 450.0 240.0 220.0 130.0
142.44 365.95 96.64 206.8 588.27 390.07 514.67 139.29 551.91 440.09 322.96 194.5 382.9 256.75 161.25 353.33 447.66 240.72 219.89 129.39
145.7 368.54 94.75 206.53 586.89 391.21 513.71 139.47 550.73 441.55 329.89 192.86 384.21 258.95 170.74 353.05 445.81 238.39 220.34 129.33
142.61 374.78 92.26 207.04 589.26 396.31 509.22 139.73 550.46 441.79 332.67 197.16 387.85 260.0 188.98 348.71 445.92 239.53 220.07 129.33
etc...
```

How can I return the column in `stock_data_5y.txt` that has the closest value of initial price/volatility to each value in the list `initial_price` or the list `volatility`??

```py
for i in stock_data_5y[0:1]: #stock_data_5y[0:1] is the first row - represents volatility
     difference = abs(i - initial_price)
```

The next step is to find which column `i` returns the minimum value, then return that column

Answer (score 0):

in numpy `array.argmin()` returns the position in the array with the minimum value

Comment: but in this case I want to find the difference between the input `initial_price` and a value in the row

Comment: I think I didn't understand your question. To find the column i with the minimum value use i = difference.argmin(). To find the value uses initial_price[i]

Comment: your question is not so clear you need to subtract each of the other rows from the first row values or what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

tried this but you know that the columns with minimum difference could change by row check this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=" ", header=None)

print(data)


for row in range(1,data.shape[0]):
    print("row {}".format(row))
    sub = data.loc[row] - data.loc[0]
    sub = list(sub.values)
    min_ = sub.index(min(sub))
    print("with min diff column: {}".format(min_))

    min_col = data.loc[0:,min_:min_]
    print(min_col)
```

this maybe was by chance or you are  it will be happening that way so the second index row which means the third row was returned

```
row 1
with min diff column: 2
        2
0    3.40
1  100.00
2   96.64
3   94.75
4   92.26
row 2
with min diff column: 2
        2
0    3.40
1  100.00
2   96.64
3   94.75
4   92.26
row 3
with min diff column: 2
        2
0    3.40
1  100.00
2   96.64
3   94.75
4   92.26
row 4
with min diff column: 2
        2
0    3.40
1  100.00
2   96.64
3   94.75
```